# Creating fishnet grid in R that sums values of points within grid instead of counts

Tags: r, vector-grid

I am very new to both coding and creating maps in R.

Is it possible to create a fishnet grid in R that sums values of points within grid instead of counts?

I have a dataset with locations for sewage system outlets and the type+amount of pollutants released. By following [this tutorial](https://urbandatapalette.com/post/2021-08-tessellation-sf/) step by step, I've managed to plot the locations of the outlets and counted+mapped the number of outlets within each grid.

```
# Following the tutorial step by step
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(mapview)


# Converting data and plot points on map
outlets_sf <- outlets.df %>%
    st_as_sf(coords = c("easting","northing"), 
    crs="+proj=utm +zone=32", remove=F)
mapview_comb = mapview(outlets_sf , cex = 3, alpha = .5, popup = NULL)

# Creating a grid with cells 4000m x 4000m 
mapview_area = st_make_grid(outlets_sf, c(4000, 4000), 
                            what ="polygons", square = T)

outlets_grid_sf = st_sf(mapview_area) %>% 
   mutate(grid_id = 1:length((mapview_area)))  # add grid ID

# count number of points in each grid
outlets_grid_sf$n_outlets = lengths(st_intersects(outlets_grid_sf, outlets_sf))

mapview(outlets_grid_sf, zcol = "n_outlets")
```

This is the output:

[image: map of concentration of sewage oulets in the Oslo fjord]

I would, however, instead of the count data, like to plot the amount of pollutants released. Meaning that the color of the fishnet grid would be dependent on the sum of pollutants released within each grid, and if two or more outlets occur within the same square, the amount of pollutants released in that grid needs to be summed before plotted.

This is some of the columns from the df I believe is relevant to this, but I've only provided to ten first rows and translated the column names so the data is easier to understand

```
           locality.name    easting northing pollutant amount.kg
1  Solumstrand avløpsanlegg  571296  6620019        Zn  9690.227
2  Fuglevik avløpsanlegg     594400  6584000        Zn 11528.705
3  NRA                       613030  6648012        Zn  9431.109
4  Sandefjord renseanlegg    569606  6550270        Zn 39131.150
5  Tønsberg renseanlegg      585419  6570185        Zn  9158.267
6  Sentralrenseanlegg        584143  6629343        Cu 19522.348
7  Sentralrenseanlegg        584143  6629343        Zn 49324.251
8  Ora avløpsanlegg          612444  6562103        Zn 18393.920
9  Bekkelaget renseanlegg    599070  6639810        Cu 21090.392
10 Bekkelaget renseanlegg    599070  6639810        Zn 32822.635
```

Answer (score 0):

Your grid is in the same coordinate system as your point data. This means you can use the `cut` function on the eastings and northings to work out which row and column of the grid your points are in.

Then you do an aggregated sum of the values based on grouping by the row and column.

Another possibility is to create the grid as a raster using the `terra` package and use its extract and process functions to work on aggregated points over cells.

There are more complex and slower ways to do this, such as making rectangular cell polygons and doing geographical intersection operations. I'd only do that if you had an irregular grid or different projections (although you could then project your points to your grid system and use the above solution). In your map your grid only looks irregular because it is projected to a Mercator grid for mapping.

If I get time I'll work up a full coded solution but there should be enough info there to get you started. `cut` is a base R function that categorises numeric data into classes based on break points.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying fast. This is my last at work before summer, but as soon as I am back I will look into your suggestion!